# Asp.net Core Razor Pages form inside Bootstrap modal not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

I would like to ask for your help, I have this modal, which properly pops up and displays the form fields, even the validation is great and the submit button also works, but the Add button doesn't and I couldn't figure out the reason why.

The code of the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<form method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="newBenchmark" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">
            Start a new benchmark
          </h5>
          <button type="reset" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input asp-for="CreateInput.Name" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="CreateInput.Name" class="form-label">
              Name
            </label>
            <span asp-validation-for="CreateInput.Name" class="text-danger">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped align-middle">
              <caption class="caption-top">
                Global
              </caption>
              <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                      Key
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                      Value
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ConfigurationItems) {
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly asp-for="@item.Item2" class="form-control-plaintext" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input readonly asp-for="@item.Item3" class="form-control-plaintext" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                }
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input asp-for="CreateInput.Key" class="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input asp-for="CreateInput.Value" class="form-control" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" asp-page-handler="AddConfigItem">
                        Add
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Start" class="btn btn-primary">
              Start
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The handler method in my PageModel class:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddConfigItem()
    {
        var scope = Scope.Global;
        if(CreateInput.Key == "" || CreateInput.Value == "")
        {
            StatusMessage = "Error: Key or value is empty.";
            
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            ConfigurationItems.Add((scope, CreateInput.Key, CreateInput.Value));
            CreateInput.Key = "";
            CreateInput.Value = "";
            
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

I ran the program in debugging mode, to see, whether it gets into the handler method, but it didn't.

Than I stalked it a bit with the browser dev tools and I saw, that there weren't any POST requests on the network by clicking on the button.

I tried to find similar problems on the net, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: A button whose `type` is `button` does nothing when clicked by default. If you explained what you want to happen when you click the button, someone might be able to suggest an alternative approach that doesn't result in the form being submitted.

Comment: That's true, just this morning it came into my head to check what's the difference between submit and button typed button. The solution is to write a js method to send an ajax POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mike Brind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134725/mike-brind) said, a button with a type="button" does nothing by default and its function is that it can be pressed. I used it, because I didn't want to submit and validate the data of the whole form, rather I had a table inside my form and I used this button to add data to this table dynamically, without reloading or submitting the form.

I could manage this, via subscribing a JS function to this button's onclick event, by writing this:

```js
// in a site.js file or embedded in html:
function addConfig(){
    /* do something here */
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" onclick="addConfig()">Add</button>
```

And after that in the JS function, in this example: `addConfig()`, I implemented an ajax POST request call and called the handler function, that I originally wanted to call by the `asp-page-handler` tag.

I can suggest this way, if you wanna do some job from a form, but without submitting or reloading the the form.